# how to integrate document search chatbot with sharePoint 2013

Tags: authentication, botframework, sharepoint-2013

I've created microsoft chatbot and integrated in SP2013 page. Now I would like chatbot to search content in sharepoint with logged in user credentials without asking for separate bot signin. Can someone help with how to pass authentication token to bot?